# flutter Camera initialize implementation

Tags: flutter

i'm new at flutter and i want to implements camera to me app but i get some error
"LateInitializationError: Field 'imgCamera' has not been initialized."

```
///main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled/MySplashPage.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';



List<CameraDescription> cameras = <CameraDescription>[];

 Future <void> main() async
 {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return const MaterialApp(
       title: 'detections image',
      home: MySplashPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

and my home page the problem is at imgCamera

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  bool isWorking = false;
  String result="";
  late CameraController cameraController;
  late CameraImage imgCamera ;
   
  final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.white,
    minimumSize: const Size(88, 44),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  );

initCamera()
  {

    cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    cameraController.initialize().then((value) {
      if(!mounted){
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        cameraController.startImageStream((imageFromStream) => {
          if(!isWorking){

              isWorking = true,
              imgCamera = imageFromStream,

          }
        });
      });
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/ia2.jpeg")
                ),
              ),
              child:  Column(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 320,
                      width: 330,
                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/ia.jpeg"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                        style: flatButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {
                          initCamera();
                        },
                      child: imgCamera == null
                        ? const SizedBox(
                          height: 270 ,
                          width: 360,
                          child: Icon(Icons.photo_camera_front, color: Colors.blueAccent, size: 40,),
                      )
                          :  AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                                child:  CameraPreview(cameraController),
                      ),
                  ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thank for your answers it will be very helpful
i try to check on youtube but all that video it was for old version of flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error said it all, you try to use the uninitialized `imgCamera == null` in your widget.

To make the code run before fixing others, try to make `imgCamera` nullable and assign `null`.

And then I think you don't need to initialize the controller everytime you want to launch the camera (`onPressed`), since you use state, I think you can utilize the `initState` function.